# Grails using query in g:select with service

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Fairly new to the Grails model, and having a little trouble getting around using a service for my database transactions.

Service:

```
class ReportService {

    def dataSource
    def listDatatypeValues(Datatype dt) {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def list = sql.rows (dt.statement)
        return list
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
def run(Long id) {

    def reportInstance = Report.get(id)
    def listPromptValues = populatePrompts(reportInstance)

    if (!reportInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'report.label', default: 'Report'), id])            
        return
    }
    [reportInstance: reportInstance, listPromptValues: listPromptValues]
}

def populatePrompts(Report rp){
    //for a prompt in the report, go out and get it's values
    rp.prompts.each {
        List list = reportService.listDatatypeValues(it.datatype)
    }
}
```

View snippet:

```
<g:if test="${reportInstance?.prompts}">
    <li class="fieldcontain">
    <g:each var="prompt" in="${reportInstance.prompts}">
    <g:if test="${prompt.datatype.type == 'DropDown'}">
    <g:select id="prompt.name" from="${listPromptValues}" name="prompt.name" value="" noSelection="['':'']"/>
        </g:if>
    </g:each>
    </li>
</g:if>
```

We have a report object, that contains prompts, which in turn contain a datatype. For any given report, when it is pulled up on the UI, it will give the report details, and then list the prompt value for a give prompt. The problem is the current setup is listing the object reference as the prompt value and not the list of values returned from the service.

And example would be Report 1 has 2 prompts, Starting Term Code and Ending Term Code. Both of them use Term Code as the datatype since it is the same SQL query, and the list returned from listDataTypeValues would be a list of 70+ term codes that are stored in the database.

Any thoughts or direction?

I tried following along with [this](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-Populate-g-select-With-a-Query-td2996222.html) but I can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a public service announcement: Using groovy sql defeats the purpose of database independence. Use HQL or the objects themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Your `populatePrompts` function isn't returning a meaningful value.  If you iterate with `collectMany` instead of `each` the value of the expression will be the concatenation of all the results from your queries. Try something like this:

```
def populatePrompts(Report rp){
    rp.prompts.collectMany {
        reportService.listDatatypeValues(it.datatype)
    } //.unique()
}
```

You may also want to call unique on the result to avoid duplicates in your `g:select` input.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much, that did it. Now one more question. It returns a list of maps. Any way to pull just the values, and not the keys?

Comment: Call `values()` on the members of the lists (e.g. `listPromptValues = populatePrompts(reportInstance)*.values()`) and you'll have a list of lists.  If you're selecting a single column, `flatten()` it and you'll have the results as a flat list.